# Why the output from `__call__` and `predict` of transformers's BERT model are different?

Tags: tensorflow, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

When playing with huggingface's transformers with tensorflow, I got different results from `__call__`, `call()` and 'predict', but I think they should be the same.

With transformers, Which one gives me the right result during training/inferencing?

I am using transformers 4.17.0 with tensorflow 2.8.0.
Code:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer,TFAutoModel,AutoConfig,TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
model = TFAutoModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')


sentence='It can be any sentence here'
encoded_input = tokenizer(text, return_tensors='tf')
output0 = model(encoded_input)[0]
output1 = model(encoded_input,training=False)[0]
output2 = model(encoded_input,training=True)[0]
output3 = model.call(encoded_input)[0]
output4 = model.call(encoded_input,training=False)[0]
output5 = model.call(encoded_input,training=True)[0]
output6 = model.predict(encoded_input.values())[0]
print(output0[0,0,:10])
print(output1[0,0,:10])
print(output2[0,0,:10])
print(output3[0,0,:10])
print(output4[0,0,:10])
print(output5[0,0,:10])
print(output6[0,0,:10])
```

The output:

```
tf.Tensor(
[-0.65482056  0.13908163 -0.7431607  -0.46033248 -0.834605    0.24891722
  1.042905    0.34481025 -0.19269213 -0.32815126], shape=(10,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[-0.65482056  0.13908163 -0.7431607  -0.46033248 -0.834605    0.24891722
  1.042905    0.34481025 -0.19269213 -0.32815126], shape=(10,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[-0.65266645 -0.03810687 -0.776067   -0.07178783 -0.9046151   0.18066
  0.82093364  0.53261256  0.06615249 -0.03404194], shape=(10,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[-0.65482056  0.13908163 -0.7431607  -0.46033248 -0.834605    0.24891722
  1.042905    0.34481025 -0.19269213 -0.32815126], shape=(10,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[-0.65482056  0.13908163 -0.7431607  -0.46033248 -0.834605    0.24891722
  1.042905    0.34481025 -0.19269213 -0.32815126], shape=(10,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[-0.7354083   0.18443112 -1.049724   -0.532299   -0.8917109   0.42158493
  1.2287179   0.6927482   0.02612726 -0.5916267 ], shape=(10,), dtype=float32)
[-0.8285751   0.2074836  -0.36887544 -0.3653527  -1.0217763   0.608446
  0.9114009   0.4278982  -0.02307865 -0.09100434]
```

Answer (score 1):

I post the same question on GitHub and got a great response from transformers team.

Generally, while training=True, the output should be different since there are dynamics in it(dropout).
when calling with `model.predict`,`encoded_input.values()` will give a wrong sequence, the correct one is :`model.predict([encoded_input["input_ids"],encoded_input["attention_mask"],encoded_input["token_type_ids"]])`

Please refer to https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/16160 for more details.